# A 'value' attribute is required for <enum> or <flag> in appcompat-v7

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I have been working on project without any issues and all of the sudden this error pops up when I try to build app. I tried deleting build folder, making project couple of times, invalidating android studio cache, restart, uninstaling instaling android studio etc. Please help, since this is driving me crazy :) Thanks!

**Error:(1) A 'value' attribute is required for < enum > or < flag >**

this is reported for appcompats color.xml file, when I removed appcompat from dependencies problem persisted referencing my project color.xml file, after i commented whole file, it persisted referencing color.xml from one other libraries which I used in project. So i think this is Android studio issue.

Comment: Could it be related to this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=151286

Comment: Thanks! Error was indeed in one of the project files, but before it was working so I guess Android studio config changed.

Comment: Same problem, also after upgrading to Android Studio 1.4. Only returning to a previous project state via subversion was a solution for me.